# Sorting tables row-wise in a TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, tableview, tablelayout, columnsorting

I am using TableLayout to display a table in Android. I want to make the table sorted when a button is clicked. This is what I tried. But it sorts each columns. What I want is to sort rows based on a column?

```
private View.OnClickListener msg = new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {

  ArrayList < String > sortobj = new ArrayList < String > ();
  ArrayList < String > sortobj1 = new ArrayList < String > ();
  ArrayList < String > sortobj2 = new ArrayList < String > ();
  ArrayList < String > sortobj3 = new ArrayList < String > ();

  for (int i = 0; i <= listobj.size(); i++) {

   sortobj.add(listobj.get(i).get(TAG_Name));
   sortobj1.add(listobj.get(i).get(TAG_Abbr));
   sortobj2.add(listobj.get(i).get(TAG_Area));
   sortobj3.add(listobj.get(i).get(TAG_Capital));

   if (listobj.get(i).get(TAG_Name).equals("West Bengal"))

    break;
  }

  Collections.sort(sortobj, Collections.reverseOrder());
  Collections.sort(sortobj1, Collections.reverseOrder());
  Collections.sort(sortobj2, Collections.reverseOrder());
  Collections.sort(sortobj3, Collections.reverseOrder());

  table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytable);

  Log.e(TAG, "Sorted in reverse order................ :");

  for (int i = 0; i < sortobj.size(); i++) {
   TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

   TextView tv0 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   TextView tv2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   TextView tv3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

   tv0.setText(sortobj.get(i));
   tv1.setText(sortobj1.get(i));
   tv2.setText(sortobj2.get(i));
   tv3.setText(sortobj3.get(i));

   row.addView(tv0);
   row.addView(tv1);
   row.addView(tv2);
   row.addView(tv3);

   table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  }
 }
};
```

Comment: You have to do it manually.

Comment: @AhamadAnees it can not be done programmatically?

Comment: I have no idea why people marked my question negative?! they couldn't answer so they give negative mark? I mean why??

Comment: Yes you can. Please include your code which adds data to the table.

Comment: if people thinks the question does not shows any effort or research, or it is of low quality, they can down-vote it. Dont think it as negative. :-) You can still improve it

Comment: @AhamadAnees i have sorted data in reverse order but could't update the same in previous table.

Comment: Wait.let me check the code

Comment: This is not the standard method of sorting, however it is ok if it works. Now what happens when you place to the table?

Comment: in emulator: first table displays and then on click sorted table appears but ,it doesn't replace the previous one and display's downward.also i want to sort the single (tv0) but rest of column doesn't sort accordingly.now what happening is i have sorted all the column which i don't wants to.I want my single column to be sort and  rest of data get sort accordingly.

Comment: give me 5 minute and i can solve this

Comment: @AhamadAnees do you want me to share my whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Problem 1:**

Each column is being sorted

**Solution:**

Sort rows not cells.
Inlude this class and create ArrayList like this `List < Row > rows= new ArrayList < Row > ();`

```
class Row implements Comparable<Row>{
    String Abb;
    String Area;
    String Capital;
    
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    String Name;

    public String getAbb() {
        return Abb;
    }

    public void setAbb(String abb) {
        Abb = abb;
    }

    public String getArea() {
        return Area;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        Area = area;
    }

    public String getCapital() {
        return Capital;
    }

    public void setCapital(String capital) {
        Capital = capital;
    }

    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Row o) {
        return this.Name.compareTo(o.Name);
    }
}
```

Now you can access each column this way : `String Name = rows.get(index).getName();` 
`rows.get(index).setName("Kerala");`

Then to sort, simply put `rows.sort();`

### **Problem 2:**

Rows are appending to the existing table

**Solution:**

Remove all rows using removeView() in a loop before adding sorted rows

Comment: i have tried to remove but only last row of table gets deleted.

Comment: removeView() deletes only one column. you have to put table.removeView(table.getChildAt(index)); in a loop. Feel free to post the result

Comment: i could able to update data onClick() but couldn't able to sort data row-wise :(

Comment: i'm trying to sort data row-wise,Actually i'm done with sorting data column-wise and updated the table then i realised i'm not getting the data accordingly though i could able to sort data column-wise but it differs when i matched the whole row.

Comment: i'm trying.i'll let you know once i done with my code.btw thanks for your replies :)

Comment: You are welcome. And i think you can delete the old comments from the post

Comment: Thanks I did it! but i did it in my way,I used a array string (Z) in which i have stored (listobj.get(i).get(var))+(listobj.get(i).get(var2))..... and then sort data using  Collections.sort(Z,Collections.reverseOrder());

Answer (score 0):

First part of the question is explained very nicely by [@Bertram Gilfoyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44237796/9640177)

For the second part you should use `removeAllViews()` instead of using `removeView()` in loop. In case your table contains headers that are not ties to the `Row` class explained in previous question or similar class, you may use a separate function to inflate the headers before rows are added back to the table.